# Weighted regression in PyMC3

Tags: python, regression, bayesian, pymc3

I'm trying to do find the parameters of a function fitted to binomial survey data. Each data point is actually a sample of size *n*. If I use a dynamic model with Bayesian forecasting (as in West & Harrison's *Bayesian Forecasting and Dynamic Models* Chapter 14.4), I can use a beta-binomial conjugate prior scheme to account for the differing sample sizes. However, I would also like to do this in PyMC3 in a way that incorporates the `data.n` column. I have set up the model as follows:

```
import pymc3 as pm
import pandas as pd
import theano.tensor as T

data = pd.DataFrame({'P':[0.98, 0.98, 0.94, 0.91, 0.82],
't' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'n':[50, 10, 40, 30, 50]})

with pm.Model() as model:
    gamma = pm.Uniform('gamma', 0.9, 1.1, testval=1.)
    zeta = pm.Uniform('zeta', 0, 0.05, testval=0.001)
    beta = pm.Uniform('beta', 0, 5, testval = 0.5)
    likelihood = pm.Normal('P_obs', mu=1/(gamma + zeta*T.exp(beta*data.t)), sd=0.005, observed=data.P)
    start = pm.find_MAP()    
    trace = pm.sample(5000, step=pm.NUTS(scaling=start), start=start)
```

(I'm also unsure about the variance term in the likelihood function. I have to make it really small for it to work. I tried a HalfCauchy, but it didn't work so well. But that isn't my main query.)

Comment: Just for clarification. Is your data a collection of zeros and ones for different groups? or something like your Dataframe?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: My apologies for the late reply! I haven't been able to solve the problem in a different way to the DGLM with Bayesian forecasting mentioned above. The data comes in as the dataframe shown above (population proportion and sample size), but can easily be converted to ones and zeros again if need be.

Comment: Oh, and on the different groups thing. It's the same group, in different years.